Early 80s USA horror comedy with a pool monster
The whole movie takes place inside a family's house, as I recall.
They have a big pool downstairs. The wife or daugter/son dissapears or are swalloved by a "pool monster" because a creature lives in the pool, not a scary one, but I remember it as quite cosy, like Jabba the Hut? Also others who use the pool face the same destiny.
I think the "monster" was created after a lightning hit the chimney.
I also think the movie ended when the monster throws up the people it has swalloved after a "final confrontation" with the father of the house.

The creature and the 'lightning' in the beginning can be found in the 1986 horror comedy TerrorVision. From Wikipedia:

When Stanley Putterman installs a brand new, "cheapest model available" satellite dish in his backyard, his family ends up getting "a lot more than just ESPN". Unfortunately for Stanley, his satellite is a perfect receptor for a load of extraterrestrial energy-garbage that just happened to be a converted mutant, zapped into his backyard: a hideous, two-ton alien blob with a never-ending appetite.

The creature eats a couple of people in an indoor pool scene. The movie ends quite differently, though, with the alien winning. Here's the trailer:



